# Filtering term count in Lucene (Java)

Tags: java, lucene

I'm currently trying to get the amount of appearences of each word in a description field using Lucene. 
F.e.

- description: BOX OF APPLES
- description: BOX OF BANANAS

output:

- BOX 2
- OF 2
- APPLES 1
- BANANAS 1

I am looking to get the word and the frequency.

The thing is I would like to filter those results to a given document, I mean only count the words in the description field of a given document.

Thanks for any assistance given.

//in answer to comment:
I have something like this:

```
public ArrayList<ObjectA> GetIndexTerms(String code) {
        try {

            ArrayList<Object> termlist = new ArrayList<ObjectA>();
            indexR = IndexReader.open(path); 
            TermEnum terms = indexR.terms();           

            while (terms.next()) {
                Term term = terms.term();
                String termText = term.text();                    
                int frequency = indexR.docFreq(term); 
                ObjectA newObj = new ObjectA(termText, frequency);
                termlist.add(newObj);                      
                }                   
            }               
            return termlist;
        } catch (Exception ex) {               
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
}
```

But i don't see how to filter it by document...

---

//TODAY!

Using the termfreqvec I can get it to work but it takes de doc id and I can't use it right. Since I used a query de "i" value starts in 0 and that's not the proper doc id. Any ideas to get this working properly?
 Thanks!

```
    TopDocs tp = indexS.search(query, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        for (int i = 0; i < tp.scoreDocs.length; i++){  
            ScoreDoc sds = tp.scoreDocs[i];
            Document doc = indexS.doc(sds.doc);
            TermFreqVector tfv = indexR.getTermFreqVector(i,"description");

            for (int j = 0; j < tfv.getTerms().length; j++) {
                String item = tfv.getTerms()[j];
                termlist.add(new TerminoDescripcion(item.toUpperCase(), tfv.getTermFrequencies()[j]));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Lucene is an *inverted* index, meaning that it makes it easy to retrieve documents based on terms, whereas you are looking for the opposite, i.e. retrieveing terms based on documents.

Hopefully, this is a recurrent problem and Lucene gives you the ability to retrieve terms for a document (*term vectors*) provided that you enabled this feature at indexing time.

See [TermVector.YES](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.TermVector.html#YES) and [Field constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#Field%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store,%20org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Index,%20org.apache.lucene.document.Field.TermVector%29) to know how to enable them at indexing time and [IndexReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermFreqVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) to know how to retrieve term vectors at search time.

Alternatively, you could re-analyze a stored field on the fly, but this may be slower, especially on large fields.

Comment: I've edited my post and added some code regarding what you told me. I can't seem to get the document id right though.

Comment: You should replace i by sds.doc in the getTermFreqVector call